# How to convert raw strings into xpath query object

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to use Scrapy to get data from web pages that follow a pattern, but it changes a bit from page to page.

Specifically, I'm trying to extract data from a table that may be found in different positions in the source code. The command I'm using is:

```
list_lines = response.xpath(".//body/table["+ str(i) +"]/tbody/node()").extract()
```

where the `str(i)` is the position of that table in the current page. I know for sure that the `i` is correct. I've read that the `response.xpath()` method receives a query. Is there any way that I can convert this string into a query?

Comment: Can you tell us what goes wrong when you run this code?

Comment: This is a normal way to write scrapy xpath. xpath indexes are 1 based, not 0 based like python lists, so maybe you are off by 1.

Comment: When I run this, list_lines is always empty. I've alredy checked that the i variable starts with 1

Comment: When i search for this xpath in the page, I am able to find the table I want, but scrapy is not recognizing it